# Move Cells With Specific Words To Specific Cells - VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I have something which I think could be quite simple to solve. However since my knowledge of VBA is very minimal I can't seem to make it work.

Here is what i'm trying to do:

[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsUTM.png)

I want to re-arrange the cells with the word ERROR, FAILED or PASSED so that they fit the correct columns. Indeed i'm parsing a web page and the order of the data changes. If i could just re-arrange so that it all fits correctly then that'd be perfect !

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub FindandcutPASS()
Dim rngA As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rngA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:H1000")

For Each cell In rngA
    If InStr(cell.Text, "ERROR") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "FAILED") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "PASSED") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    End If

Next cell

End Sub

Sub FindandcutFAIL()
    Set rngA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:I1000")
For Each cell In rngA
    If InStr(cell.Text, "ERROR") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "FAILED") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "PASSED") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next cell

End Sub

Sub FindandcutERROR()
    Set rngA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J1000")
For Each cell In rngA
    If InStr(cell.Text, "ERROR") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "FAILED") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    ElseIf InStr(cell.Text, "PASSED") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

PS: My code only works when I just do part of it :

```
Sub FindandcutPASS()
Dim rngA As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rngA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:H1000")

For Each cell In rngA
    If InStr(cell.Text, "ERROR") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J13").Select
        Selection.Value = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Thank you for any help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed for me, since my data was a JSON i just parsed it with a json converter from https://codingislove.com/excel-json/ :) feel free though, if you want to achieve what i'm describing to continue this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see it, you're sorting each row individually. `Pass, Fail, Error` is kind of a custom ordering but it luckily coincides with descending order in the scope of your data. Try this short code:

```
Sub sortAllRows()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:J1000").Rows
        r.Sort r, xlDescending
    Next
End Sub
```

p.s., the `"` stuff in your data is noisy, do some pre-processing to remove them at the beginning. A single statement will do:

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:J1000").Replace Chr(34), vbNullString
```

p.s.2 I realize that if some rows are incomplete, some values migth be misplaced. But this should get you started.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply ! I actually fixed it by starting over and directly parsing it with a json converter for VBA (because yes the data was in json form). But i'll definitely keep this for some other time because it's very useful to know !